# How to draw a horizontal percentage bar plot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, pie-chart

Is it possible to draw a similar graph using matplotlib that I've attached below?

[image]

Comment: You could try and using stacked bar graphs which look similar: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What you need is stacked `barh` which is a horizontal bar chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/broken_barh.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

start = 0
never = 54
seldom = 43
undecided = 3

ax.broken_barh([(start, never), (never, never+seldom), (never+seldom, never+seldom+undecided)], [10, 9], facecolors=('#6259D8', '#E53F08', '#FDB200'))
ax.set_ylim(5, 15)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_yticks([15, 25])
ax.set_xticks([0, 25, 50, 75, 100])

ax.set_axisbelow(True) 

ax.set_yticklabels(['Q1'])
ax.grid(axis='x')
ax.text(never-6, 14.5, "54%", fontsize=8)
ax.text((never+seldom)-6, 14.5, "43%", fontsize=8)
ax.text((never+seldom+undecided)+2, 14.5, "3%", fontsize=8)

fig.suptitle('This is title of the chart', fontsize=16)

leg1 = mpatches.Patch(color='#6259D8', label='Never')
leg2 = mpatches.Patch(color='#E53F08', label='Seldom')
leg3 = mpatches.Patch(color='#FDB200', label='Undecided')
ax.legend(handles=[leg1, leg2, leg3], ncol=3)

plt.show()
```

This is the result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 7):

Using [barh](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html) method, something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

never = [74]
seldom = [18]
undecided = [8]

y = [0]

plt.barh(y, never, color='#b5ffb9', edgecolor='white')
plt.barh(y, seldom, left=never, color='#f9bc86', edgecolor='white')
plt.barh(y, undecided, left=[100-i for i in undecided], color='#a3acff', edgecolor='white')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]